# How do I programmatically import a Crystal Reports SubReport into a Report Section in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report object defined as follows:

```
private CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass rep;
```

I am trying to Import a SubReport into Section 1 of the report. I have tried variants of the following code:
    rep.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreport

There seems to be conflict between:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
```

and

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer
```

Has anybody programmatically imported a Sub-Report in Crystal using VS2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anybody else who comes across this problem, the solution is:

```
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass rep;
            ReportClientDocumentWrapper doc = (ReportClientDocumentWrapper)rep.ReportClientDocument;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sec = doc.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.ReportHeaderArea.Sections[0];
            doc.SubreportController.ImportSubreport("SubReport", csr.ReportFileName, sec);
            rep.OpenSubreport("SubReport").SetDataSource(csr.ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: is it possible for Crystal Reports 2008, I mean without RAS libs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still might need this. Here is the solution. Try it and work!!!

You need to import these References:

- CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc
- CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers
- CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel

here is the code:

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();

rpt.Load("reportPath"));

rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
```

Inside the main report you must have a subreport and with this code it re-import from the dynamic path

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sec = rpt.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[0];
rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreport("subreportname", "subreportpath", sec);
```

Answer (score -3):

Adding sub-reports dynamically is not supported in Crystal Reports as of now.